# Why do I see the lines of the UV editor after adding colour to my objects?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I used to UV editor to map out my objects and being able to paint on them.
However, I keep seeing these lines in Material preview or when I render.

Why do I see the lines of the UV editor after adding colour to my objects?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you increase the Bleed option in the N panel > Tool > Options, then paint again?

Comment: Ah yes! that does make a difference. I do have to go over my object twice in order to really get rid of the marks. That is okay right?

Comment: could you please share an object with the problem? Don't forget to pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)